# How to check version of AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

I am thinking about upgrading my current project, but I don't know which version I have. Is there a way to tell?

Comment: have you found some thing?

Comment: No. All I know is that given the "Gowalla" tags in the file headers, it means it was one of the first versions from 2011. That said, all I know is that it's NOT version 2. As such, the version I have is inconsequential. It serves its purpose for now, but an upgrade would be good in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you can't**.

[AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) saves its version to the `CHANGES` file, you do can't find any version mark in any source files.

If the version number is very important to your project, you can scan the `UIKit+AFNetworking` folder and `AFNetworking` folder in the source code hosting on Github. According to commit log, to diff some specific code snippet for checking if it exists in a specific version.

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer. I also have the question of determining the version of code in an inherited code base. Should be obvious but isn't.

Answer (score 9):

You can always check `Podfile.lock` it will show you the last version and all its dependencies.

Comment: If he was using CocoaPods, he wouldn't have this problem... :/

Answer (score 0):

If there's a ["`CHANGES`" file](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/CHANGES) found somewhere within your AFNetworking directory, that should contain the version number.

Comment: There is no such file in mine. The only indication of version I can get is in the tops of files where it mentions "
Copyright (c) 2011 Gowalla (http://gowalla.com/)"